# Getting all items of QComboBox - PyQt4 (Python)

Tags: python, get, pyqt4, qcombobox

I have A LOT of `QComboBoxes`, and at a certain point, I need to fetch every item of a particular `QComboBox` to iterate through.
Although I could just have a list of items that correspond to the items in the `QComboBox`, I'd rather get them straight from the widget itself (there are a huge amount of `QComboBoxes` with many items each).

Is there any functions / methods that will do this for me?
(Eg:

```
 QComboBoxName.allItems()
```

)
I've looked through the class reference but couldn't find anything relevant.

I've thought of a few messy methods, but I don't like them.
(Like iterating through the `QComboBox` by changing the index and getting the item, etc).

---

Python 2.7.1
IDLE 1.8
Windows 7
PyQt4

Comment: This is an old post, but for completeness, it might be worth considering using a model to populate the combo and working with that.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can just reference an item using `.itemText()`:

```
AllItems = [QComboBoxName.itemText(i) for i in range(QComboBoxName.count())]
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know you wanted the item's text, not the item reference. Either way, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the accepted answer, you can actually give you combobox a **method** callable using `combo_box.allItems()`, by doing this:

```
    setattr(combo_box, "allItems", lambda: [combo_box.itemText(i) for i in range(self.ui.combo_box.count())])
    print(combo_box.allItems()) # Works just fine!
```

I believe it has to be done in the scope where `combo_box` was born, otherwise `setattr` fails.
Tested in PyQt5 and Python 3.7.