# How can i use a for loop to collect data from different combobox in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm pretty embarassed, but i need to understand the sintax needed to build a for cycle to append 36 ComboBox text inputs into the same list.
This is the code i used:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow


from PyQt5 import uic

class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("UI_psi.ui", self)

        self.avanti_psi.clicked.connect(self.sdq_page)
        self.avanti_psi.clicked.connect(self.psi_data)



    def sdq_page(self):
        uic.loadUi("UI_sdq.ui", self)
        self.Avanti_sdq.clicked.connect(self.indici_page)
    def indici_page(self):
        uic.loadUi("UI_indici.ui", self)
        print()
    def psi_data(self):
        psiData = []
        psiData.append(self.psi_1.currentText())
        psiData.append(self.psi_2.currentText())
        psiData.append(self.psi_3.currentText())

        print(psiData)







app = QApplication([])
window = Ui()

window.show()
app.exec()
```

I called the function "psi_data", and i feel really dumb adding all the ComboBox's current text as i did...but i can't figure out how to iterate every combobox in the UI_psi.ui and add em to the list psiData[]!

Comment: Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479915/getting-all-items-of-qcombobox-pyqt4-python) and let  me know if that helped.

Comment: You'll have to find your own way of collecting that data. If they are correctly *named* (for example, their names all start with `psi_` and are correctly ordered), you can use something like `psiData = [getattr(self, 'psi_{}'.format(i)).currentText() for i in range(1, 37)]`. Be careful that you should not use `loadUi` more than once on the same instance, as it might give you unexpected results; use different windows or a `QStackedWidget` to have different interfaces while keeping the same window.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480072/6393476). I believe your `psi_data` function should look like this:

```py
def psi_data(self):
    self.psiData = []
    self.psiData += [self.psi_1.itemText(i) for i in range(self.psi_1.count())]
    self.psiData += [self.psi_2.itemText(i) for i in range(self.psi_2.count())]
    self.psiData += [self.psi_3.itemText(i) for i in range(self.psi_3.count())]
```